# How to communicate usb serial in c# Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have use xamarin in visual studio 2017 professional.

I have try to communicate with usb serial communication with device **X** using below link....
[Xamarin lib for usb serial communication](https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://github.com/anotherlab/UsbSerialForAndroid&hl=en-IN)
 But when i plug usb cable in phone (not connect with device **X**) got port.isconnection it comes always **true** result, but i have just plug cable in phone.
Why i am getting connected true always...

After connect cable with device **X** and try to write something on device it not write on device

Send some bytes array to device **X**, but not getting any response.

How can i resolve it?

Comment: Did you find any source code ?